# SharePoint Rest Document library

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am creating a custom page writing the HTML and javascript for a SharePoint site. I would like to embed document libraries inside my custom html I am writing in SharePoint designer.

I have nto found a way to easily embed document libraries in custom html but did stumble on some documentation for a rest api. I figured I could use this and write my own ajax app in the html for users to navigate the document library.

I am currently trying with this javascrip just to see if I can pull html or JSON for a document library contents:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var folderUrl = "x/x/x/testDocumentLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Folders,Files";

$.getJSON(url,function(data,status,xhr){

    for(var i = 0; i < data.Files.length;i++){
        console.log(data.Files[i].Name);    
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < data.Folders.length;i++){
        console.log(data.Folders[i].Name);    
    }
});
 </script>
```

I am not sure if I am using the right url for the `folderUrl` variable.

In order to conduct some tests what is `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeURL` pulling? I am trying to see if I can work backwards and create the URL manually first with out the SP function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The `folderUrl` variable in your example code should end with the path to the library; everything up until `/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, so `/x/x/x/testDocumentLibrary` where `/x/x/x/` is the server-relative path to the site on which the library resides.

The `_spPageContextInfo` object provides two variations of server-relative URL, one for the current site (called a "web" in SharePoint jargon) and one for the current site *collection* (called a "site" in SharePoint jargon). Appropriately, these properties are labeled `webServerRelativeURL` and `siteServerRelativeURL`. Both of these are server-relative, meaning that they exclude the first part of the domain name. (Instead of `https://constoso.com/sites/stackoverflow` they'll give you `/sites/stackoverflow`.)

For a REST call, you probably want the absolute URL, not the server-relative URL. You can access the web and site absolute URLs through `_spPageContextInfo`'s properties `webAbsoluteURL` and `siteAbsoluteURL`.

If the list/library you're accessing is on the current site where your REST is running, use the `webAbsoluteURL` property.

Comment: What if the page I am building, I just copied an older page in designer and re named it, would this all work or would I need to create the page in share point website first?

Comment: It should work, assuming you copied it to the same site. See my updated answer for details about the format of the string in your `folderUrl` variable.